# JS while прокрутить цикл до выполнения определенного условия

Tags: javascript, циклы, ecmascript-6

Пытаюсь прокрутить цикл до выполнения определенного условия, но он просто виснет, не давая никаких выводов. Файрфокс приходиться снимать с задачь... Что я упустил, логически ведь все верно. Должно быть без доп. функций, разве что с анонимными. Думал resole\reject сделать, но кажется перебором оно здесь.

```
var imgNum = 1;
    while (imgNum !== 0) {
        fetch('../images/бетон-' + imgNum + '.jpg', { method: 'HEAD' }).then(function (r) {
            if (r && r.ok) {
                console.log('okie! ' + imgNum);
                imgNum++;
            } else {
                console.log('-_--sp');
                imgNum = 0;
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('-_--' + error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Вы уверены что у вас функция заходит в else? Зависание обычно означает бесконечное выполнение, т.е цикл

Comment: @danilshik у меня почему-то даже первый,2й результат в консоль не попадает.

Comment: а что выводится?

Comment: @ThisMan ничего, виснет жутко.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> логически ведь все верно

*логически неверно*

`fetch` - асинхронная функция, ни одно присвоение `imgNum` в цикле `while` не выполнится, так как до выполнения `function (r) { ... }` дело не дойдет. Цикл будет крутиться бесконечно с значением `imgNum` равным `1`.

```
var imgNum = 1;
callFetch();

function callFetch() {
  fetch('../images/бетон-' + (imgNum++) + '.jpg', { method: 'HEAD' }).then(function(r) {
    if (r && r.ok) {
      console.log('okie! ' + (imgNum - 1));
      callFetch();
    } else {
      console.log('-_--sp');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: спасибо. где-то так и предполагал. Только, не подскажете, как это наиболее грамотно можно исправить?

Comment: @CodeGust Сначала надо понять, что Вы хотите сделать. Сколько изображений должно быть загружено?

Comment: в том и смысл всего, количество изображений неизвестно. То есть они лежат и появляются в папке пронумерованные и цикла загружает все. Как только ссылка последнего индекса дает ошибку, это значит, что все загружено и цикл прекращает работу загрузки и динамического создания элементов.

Comment: @CodeGust А-а-а, понял.

Comment: @CodeGust вы можете еще обратить внимание на `async - await` . Вероятно они позволят вам написать ваш код как вы его представляли.

Comment: спасиБо! сработало. интересно бы еще без имени функции сделать, здесь - как самовызывающаяся функция, а сделать как бы блоком кода...

Comment: @zalex да, спасибо, попробовать надо.

Comment: `ни одно присвоение imgNum в цикле while не выполнится, так как до выполнения function (r) { ... } дело не дойдет.` Но строго говоря - когда то же дойдет ?  Насколько я понимаю мы имеем в данном случае бесконечный цикл запросов и не доходит дело до `then` исключительно потому что мы ограничены  в производительности. Если же представить что ресурс производительности бесконечен, мы в итоге хотя бы раз получим то что будет выполнено в `then`, а в нашем идеальном мире мы так же получаем бесконечное выполнение `then` ?  Или это все же работает как то по-другому ? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @zalex Выполнение кода в javascript - однопоточное. Для вызова асинхронного колбэка страница должна перейти в состояние *idle*. Пока код крутится в плотном цикле `while`, этого не произойдет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за разъяснение. Т.е. если в цикле поставить паузу, то колбэк выполнится ?

Comment: @zalex это зависит от того, что мы понимаем под "паузой" в javascript-е )

Comment: Справедливо. Setinterval тут видимо не даст ни какого эффекта. Вообще надо бы почитать как устроена асинхронность, возможно тогда станет понятнее. Порекомендуете литературу по этому поводу кроме Google  ? Спасибо.